# redirect all traffic from just the sub domain to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following setup. I used to have my api as a sub domain on my main website for instance.

```
example.com
api.example.com
```

I have completely removed my api to its own domain on a different server example.

```
myapi.com
```

I want to redirect all the traffic from my old sub domain.

```
api.example.com
```

to

```
myapi.com
```

without affecting the main website traffic, I would really appreciate some help with this my knowledge of advanced redirects is limited, so thought it was worth asking the community.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To redirect the subdomain to domain, you can use the following Permanent Redirect in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks @starkeen going to give this a try ;)

Comment: This works but after using postman it doesnt seem to send the post data

Comment: ok apparently it can't be done like this i am going to look for another solution thanks

Comment: Have you found the solution for this?